# java sockets client single connection

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to connect from a J2ee web application to another server(Socket server) which supports one connection TCP connection. The socket server supports one connection from WEB , that means once the connection is open its should not close for any request.

So my doubts is how can I keep this connection alive for n request & then handle the same getting response for that request it self? (Synchronize it)

Also what if I have two application accessing the same Socket server (How do I maintain one connection)? What if the web system get clustered?

1. Forming Single Client for n request from web?
2. How to handle the response from Socket server for that request (validation sort, to get appropriate response for the request)
3. if the app server is having two or more application , how to handle the socket connection as the one connection from App server?
4. what if the app server has to be clustered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a version of the server which accepts multiple simultaneous connections (either modify the server, or make a proxy server). This will solve all these problems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Forming Single Client for n request from web?

   Yes, and it's advised to open and close connection for each request.
2. How to handle the response from Socket server for that request (validation sort, to get appropriate response for the request)

   Response from socket server is usually character sequences, you should consult the socket server's documentation and then write the String parser accordingly.
3. if the app server is having two or more application , how to handle the socket connection as the one connection from App server?

   Implement a queuing or connection pooling system for socket client, and thus it'll be guaranteed that only 1 request will happen at once.
4. what if the app server has to be clustered?

   Then you need to separate the socket client module to a different application, and hence there will be only 1 pooling/queuing system.

It will be  the best if you can modify the "socket server" to be able to handle simultaneous multiple requests. There is a framework for this and implementation is fairly simple: [Apache MINA](http://mina.apache.org/)